# Odd SyntaxError when trying to assign a var after a dict.update in python 2.7

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Having a stupid moment here and could use some help.  I'm just trying to create a simple script in python 2.7 for importing json via an API.  The accounts_json is something like:

```
{u'name': u'admin', u'isOrg': False, u'isImported': False, u'isAdmin': True, u'fullName': u'', u'id': u'8efb2bfd-ae3f-4665-9d2e-13287a4ffe0e', u'isActive': True}
```

For whatever reason, I'm getting a `SyntaxError` on one of my variables in a block of code like this:

```
password_dict = {
    "password":"blahblah"
}
if not accountsJson["isOrg"]:
    accountsJson.update(password_dict)
to_import = json.dumps(accountsJson)
```

This results in:

```
    to_import = accountsJson
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I separate things out in the python interpreter everything takes:

```
>>> if not accountsJson["isOrg"]:
...     accountsJson.update(password_dict)
... 
>>> accountsJson
{u'name': u'admin', u'isOrg': False, u'isImported': False, u'isAdmin': True, u'fullName': u'', 'password': u'blahblah', u'id': u'8efb2bfd-ae3f-4665-9d2e-13287a4ffe0e', u'isActive': True}
>>> to_import = accountsJson
>>> to_import
{u'name': u'admin', u'isOrg': False, u'isImported': False, u'isAdmin': True, u'fullName': u'', 'password': u'blahblah', u'id': u'8efb2bfd-ae3f-4665-9d2e-13287a4ffe0e', u'isActive': True}
>>> to_import["password"]
u'blahblah'
```

I've tried both with/without `json.loads` doesn't seem to impact things. 
 What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The block of code presented is perfectly valid Python 2.x code, at least syntactically.

Comment: check white spaces any tabs?  replace with spaces

Comment: Are you certain your code here is identical to what is in your script? If I had to guess you missed a parenthesis  or bracket which commonly results in a syntax error being thrown on the wrong line.